# Checking if it palindrome using recursive way using javascript. Not able to get the desired result

Tags: javascript

Checking if it palindrome using recursive way using javascript. How should I remove special characters and spaces? output for console.log of 'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama' is wrong. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
function isPalindromeHelper(left,right,str){
  if(left >= right) return true;
  if(str[left] !== str[right]) return false;
  return isPalindromeHelper(left+1, right-1, str);
}

function isPalindrome(s){
  return isPalindromeHelper(0, s.length-1, s);
}

console.log(isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama")); //true
console.log(isPalindrome("radar")); //true
console.log(isPalindrome('amanaplanacanalpanama')) //true
console.log(isPalindrome("race a car")); //false
console.log(isPalindrome('pala')) //false
```

Comment: "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" is only a palindrome if you ignore spaces and punctuation. Your function doesn't do that. Your recursive calls should also be calling `isPalindromeHelper` not `isPalindrome`. `isPalindrome` also needs to `return` a value

Answer (score 0):

Given your test cases you should:

- skip non alpha characters
- compare in a lower case

Also you could use only 1 function:

```js
function isPalindrome(s, left = 0, right = s.length - 1){
  if(left >= right){
    return true;
  }
  
  if(/\W/.test(s[left])){
    return isPalindrome(s, left + 1, right);
  }
  
  if(/\W/.test(s[right])){
    return isPalindrome(s, left, right - 1);
  }
  
  if(s[left].toLowerCase() !== s[right].toLowerCase()){
    return false;
  }
  return isPalindrome(s, left + 1, right - 1);
}

console.log(isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama")); //true
console.log(isPalindrome("race a car")); //false
```